# Clean commit using rebase

Tags: git

I've 5 commits :

```
git commit --allow-empty -m 1
git commit --allow-empty -m 2
git commit --allow-empty -m 3
git commit --allow-empty -m 4
git commit --allow-empty -m 5
```

I would like to clean up commit so I tried

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

but :

```
   Nothing to do
```

How to organise commits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5 --keep-empty
```